# Creating numerous Firebase objects

Tags: javascript, firebase

Initially when I started using Firebase I was having trouble setting data in a certain format and the solution I came up with was to create a new firebase each time I wanted a different path, whereas on the Firebase website it almost always used child selectors. For example:

```
var groupRef = new Firebase(FB + "/group");
var groupUserRef = new Firebase(FB + "/group/" + groupID + "/users/" + uid);

var connectedGroupsRef = new Firebase(FB + "/connectedGroups/" + uid + "/" + groupID);
var connectedGroups = connectedGroupsRef.set(true);
```

Is there any harm in doing it this way?  In the documentation it doesn't seem to use this method as much as I do so I was concerned that doing it the way I do it could have some issues down the road.

Comment: according documentation it has the same effect as using .child() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Firebase guide on understanding its data structure](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references):

> It's possible to directly access child nodes in the data as well. For example, to point to Mary Chen's name, simply append users/mchen/name to the URL:
>
> `new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data/users/mchen/name");`
>
> We can achieve the same result from an existing parent reference by using the child() API call:
>
> `var rootRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data');`
> `rootRef.child('users/mchen/name');`

So there is no difference in efficiency between creating a direct reference to a child node or going through one or more `child` calls.

The actual data binding is abstracted away behind these calls in the JavaScript client library. This is also how Firebase ensures that it only has to download the data once, even if you have multiple references to it.